# Why a partial eclipse is apparent only as an artifact on a smartphone camera?

Tags: artifacts, smartphone, eclipse

Both the front and back cameras of my phone did not "pick up" a partial eclipse, but it did appear as an artifact on the image. If I do not see a crescent on the sun itself, why the crescent shows up in the artifact? And why is there such an artifact in the first place?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer?  A cell phone camera is woefully incapable of shooting photos of the sun.  A cell phone camera typically has a fixed-aperture lens with an aperture of around f/2, a maximum shutter speed of 1/8000th (I think) and probably a minimum sensitivity of ISO 50 or ISO 100.

I had some trouble with sensor saturation on my 5D Mark IV at f/40, ISO 100, 1/8000th of a second, with a Hoya R72 IR filter (which blocks almost all visible light).  So not even counting the filter, your camera at its fastest (lowest light gathering setting) was getting 512x as much light hitting the sensor, and counting the filter, it's probably closer to 50,000x.

And as the other answer mentioned, the artifact is a reflection caused by the interior of the lens not being perfectly black and the antireflective coatings on the lens not quite preventing 100% of reflections between the various glass elements that make up the lens.  Different lenses handle lens flare in different ways.  Some lenses do a really good job of diffusing the lens flare (resulting in a slightly washed out image without significant artifacts), but others don't, resulting in bright flare spots.

Answer (score 3):

The two are alike in shape but the greater intensity of the primary image overloads the sensor creating a glare that interferes with the detail of the edges.

The artifact is an internal reflection greatly reduced in intensity and offset so it is visible against the darker coloured sky.